# SQLite3 select last event by user

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table 'events'.

```
| id | event_type | by_user | asset |       time |
|  1 | owner      | a       |    10 | 1111111111 |
|  2 | updated    | b       |    20 | 1111111112 |
|  3 | owner      | a       |    30 | 1111111113 |
|  4 | owner      | c       |    20 | 1111111114 |
|  5 | updated    | a       |    10 | 1111111115 |
|  6 | owner      | a       |    20 | 1111111118 |
```

I would like to select the assets where user 'a' was the last user
with an 'owner' event_type.  So in this example the id's 1, 3 and 6 (the
assets 10, 20 and 30 are owned by user 'a').

Basically, based on the events, I want to find the assests owned by user 'a'.

Comment: And what about asset 30?

Comment: your correct, i'll up date the question.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I would like to build a query that selects the last row where user 'a' had the owner event type. Basically, based on the events, I want to find the assests owned by user 'a'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what correlated subqueries are for:

```
SELECT * FROM events e
  WHERE event_type='owner'
   AND time=(SELECT MAX(e_inner.time) FROM events e_inner
      WHERE e_inner.asset=e.asset AND e_inner.event_type='owner')
```

Will give you the event that is "for each asset, show the last ownership event". If you want it for specific assets or specific owners, just add an appropriate WHERE clause

Your question is ripe for breakage if you aren't guaranteeing uniqueness of {time, event_type, asset}. This will return all *n* rows if you have *n* users being assigned ownership at the exact same time.